# WaitForPagetoLoad function issue in webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I am using Waitforpagetoload in my automation,

When i give 20000 test case fails but passes if i give 60000.

when i compare the time by printing the current time in milli secs, the page is not taking more than 50ms.

How exactly the waitforpagetoload function works?

Comment: `waitforpagetoload` waits for the full page, i.e. waits until the page and all its resources are fully rendered. Does your page (and all its resources) load in under 20 seconds in your browser?

Comment: If you're only wanting to wait for a specific element I'd suggest using an ExpectedCondition instead

Comment: @Carlo: My page is getting loaded in < 1sec(Which i have checked by printing milliseconds) but still it throws an error when i keep 20sec but works fine with 60sec

Comment: @Alex,: In my case i have to check content for full page, where i'm using the above method

Answer (score 0):

By default the WebDriver waits until the page is completely loaded and you don't need to do nothing. In fact when the WebDriver gets some page will be waiting for the onload event that is generated by the browser once the page is fully loaded.

In case your page is loading data through Ajax after the onload event is triggered, you could use a different solutions to detect when the page is fully loaded such as ask for the elements that are loaded through Ajax, so when all these elements are present in the page you are sure the page is fully loaded.

Are you using the method Waitforpagetoload for any other reason?

Comment: Yes, I'm using waitforpagetoload only to wait until my webpage is loaded.